# Retrieve all the keys of a MongoDb Nested Document using Java

Tags: java, mongodb

I have a example Document Like:

```
{ 
   "_id":{ 
      "$oid":"5db183192bc7c53f24c6b1b4"
   },
   "name":"Jack",
   "addresses":[ 
      { 
         "type":1.0,
         "street":"123 My Street",
         "city":"Bedford Falls",
         "state":"NJ"
      },
      { 
         "type":2.0,
         "street":"456 My Street",
         "city":"Bedford Falls",
         "state":"NJ"
      },
      { 
         "type":3.0,
         "street":"789 My Street",
         "city":"Bedford Falls",
         "state":"NJ"
      }
   ]
}.
```

Now I want to retrieve the values of the keys(type,street,name). How can I do that using Java?

I am getting the keys and their values up to the array but not after that.

```
package utils;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

import org.bson.BSONObject;
import org.bson.Document;
import org.bson.types.ObjectId;

import com.mongodb.BasicDBObject;
import com.mongodb.DB;
import com.mongodb.DBCollection;
import com.mongodb.DBCursor;
import com.mongodb.DBObject;
import com.mongodb.MongoClient;

public class TestClass extends MongoConnector{
    public static MongoClient mongoClient = null;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        TestClass demo =new TestClass();
        mongoClient = demo.createConnection("*********", "******", "******", "*****", "*****");
        DB databaseName =mongoClient.getDB("sampledata");
        DBCollection coll = databaseName.getCollection("Mule");
        String[] keyNames = {"name","type","street"};
        ObjectId id= new ObjectId("4fce8cca5a37d2376c78017f");
                BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
                query.put("_id",id);
                DBCursor cursor = coll.find();
                ArrayList arr = new ArrayList();
                String str;
                while (cursor.hasNext()) {
                    System.out.println(cursor.next());
                    for (String key : keyNames) {
                        str=cursor.curr().get(key).toString();
                        arr.add(key+":"+str);
                    }
                }
        System.out.println(arr);
            mongoClient.close();
    }
}
```

I expect to get only the values and keys as a List but when type is given it throws a null Pointer exception. Can anyone help on this

Answer (score 0):

Rivu,

You are using a document with array of nested document. You need to get "addresses", and after that, iterate in the documents present in that array.

Check the doc [Array of Embedded Documents](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-array-of-documents/)

```
        DB databaseName =client.getDB("sampledata");
        DBCollection coll = databaseName.getCollection("Mule");
        String[] keyRootNames = {"name"};
        ObjectId id= new ObjectId("4fce8cca5a37d2376c78017f");
        BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
        query.put("_id",id);
        DBCursor cursor = coll.find();
        ArrayList arr = new ArrayList();
        String str;
        while (cursor.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(cursor.next());
            for (String key : keyRootNames) {
                str=cursor.curr().get(key).toString();
                arr.add(key+":"+str);
            }
            if(null != cursor.curr().get("addresses")){
                BasicDBList addresses = (BasicDBList) cursor.curr().get("addresses");
                for (int i = 0; i < addresses.size() ; i++){
                    BasicDBObject nestedDocument = (BasicDBObject) addresses.get(i);
                    arr.add(String.format("%s:%s", "type", nestedDocument.get("type")));
                    arr.add(String.format("%s:%s", "street", nestedDocument.get("street")));
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(arr);
```